# Apache Shiro. 'Remember me' and cookies don't working

Tags: shiro, remember-me

I am developing a vaadin-based project using Apache Shiro 1.2 for security. I have a problem with 'remember me' feature. I try to use CookieRememberMeManager as RememberMeManager, but after authentification Subject.isRemembered() always returns false.

```
public class ApplicationSecurityManager extends DefaultSecurityManager {

    public ApplicationSecurityManager(Realm singleRealm) {
        super(singleRealm);
        setRememberMeManager(new CookieRememberMeManager());
    }
}
```

I set SecurityManager in init method of GuiceFilter.

```
    final Realm realm = new ApplicationSecurityRealm();
    final SecurityManager securityManager = new ApplicationSecurityManager(realm);
    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
```

When I try to login to my application, all works fine except 'remember me' feature.
Code:

```
    final Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username,password);
    token.setRememberMe(rememberMe);
    currentUser.login(token);
```

Application have no exceptions, and i could't resolve this problem using debug.
I use Apache Tomcat 7.0.40, can it to forbid cookies?

P.s. Sorry for my English, I'm not from an English-speaking country.

Answer (score 1):

I realize it has been a year, but this question is getting a fair number of views, so I thought I'd post some information.

Subject.isRemembered() is a little tricky in Shiro. It only returns true if the Subject has a valid Remember Me setting (cookie, etc) AND the Subject is not Authenticated. Details here: http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/subject/Subject.html#isRemembered()

So, I suspect that your Remember Me is working fine, but your expectations for Subject.isRemembered() doesn't match what the method actually does.